# php regex to separate out characters stuck to left, right or in the middle

Tags: php, regex

Looking for a php regex that will allow me to separate out certain characters from words (if they're sticking to the left or right of the word, or even anywhere within the word).

For example,

```
hello. -> hello .
.hello -> . hello
hello.hello -> hello . hello
```

I have the below code but it won't work for all cases. Please note that $value could be '.', '?', or any character.

```
$regex = "/(?<=\S)\\" . $value . "|\\" . $value . "(?=\S)/";
$this->str = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($word) {
    return ' ' . $word[0];
}, $this->str);
```

Also, please help with specifying the part where I can turn on (or off) the 3rd condition.

**[UPDATE]**
I think there might be confusion about exact requirements. Let me try to be more specific. I want a regex which will help me seperate out certain characters which are either at the end or the beginning of a group of text. What is group of text? Group of text could be any length (>=1) and contain any characters however it must begin with a-z or 0-9. Again, would be nice if this aspect would be highlighted in solution so that if we want group of text to begin&end with more characters (not just a-z or 0-9) it's possible.

```
$character = '.', string is ".hello.world." => ". hello.world ."
$character = '.', string is ".1ello.worl2." => ". 1ello.worl2 ."
$character = '.', string is ".?1ello.worl2." => ".?1ello.worl2 ."
$character = '.', string is "4/5.5" => "4/5.5"
$character = '.', string is "4.?1+/5" => "4.?1+/5"
$character = '.', string is ".4/5.5." => ". 4/5.5 ."
$character = '/', string is ".hello?.world/" => ".hello?.world /"
$character = '/', string is ".hello?.worl9/" => ".hello?.worl9 /"
```

Hope, its more clear now.

Comment: Can't you just str_replace `.` with ` . `?

Comment: Will cause an issue if i want to turn off last condition where hello.hello remains hello.hello. Also, 'hey .hello' will become 'hey  . hello' (notice the extra space after 'hey' (which is well not the biggest problem but was looking for a solution to avoid that).

Comment: Use `preg_quote` for espacing your $value instead of "\\". Might look better and provide a more robust solution..

Comment: The `hello . hello` and `hello .` examples have a space separating the `.` and word, is that incorrect?

Comment: @chris85 yes, thats correct.

Comment: You can also use a [word-boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) based regex like [`\b(?=\.)|(?<=\.)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/mE6uC9/1) or without third option [`\b(?=\.\B)|(?<=\B\.)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/xO1xF4/2) and replace with space. See [demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/546616)

Comment: @bobblebubble your solution seems to work for me. Do you want to answer the question?

Comment: @N.M.: [It does not work](https://regex101.com/r/mE6uC9/2) if we take into account [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364369/php-regex-to-separate-out-characters-stuck-to-left-right-or-in-the-middle/36365075?noredirect=1#comment60354659_36365075).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, it doesn't work. The comment was probably made later.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. I give my vote to @WiktorStribiżew  for his effort. Maybe add more detail to your question. :) It's difficult to read out the exact requirements. Here is my last [PHP Demo](https://eval.in/546797).

Comment: @N.M. Maybe [something like this](https://eval.in/546999) is all you need.

Comment: my_func('a./b', '.'); gives "a ./b". Would want it to be the same.
Wouldn't want anything to change if '.' is found in the middle of a set of characters [a-z].

Comment: If you are going to update your question with more requirements and test cases, please do that once. Otherwise, this is an XY problem that won't help future readers, and makes answering this question impossible.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please give me a single regex which "allows me to separate out certain characters from words (if they're sticking to the left or right of the word)" for all cases and i will accept that answer. The above condition is copied/pasted from the question. I know the question also has a 3rd condition "even anywhere within the word", but that is optional.

Comment: My first regex already does it. You started adding exceptions like if it is between digits. Please provide your definition of a "word", there are different ways of naming a "word". For me, a word should only contain letters. You name a "a./b" a word - why? To answer a question, it should contain clarifications for all such requirements. Regex is very context sensitive, it is not possible to "give one regex" to cover *all* cases you may have in your input, and that we cannot see (neither test against).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i believe 'a' is an indefinite particle which is a word [http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAParticle.htm]. Again, i don't want to get technical here, but i'm just trying to look for something that will work for my use case. I appreciate all your help. Thanks.

Comment: Or like this: [`\b(?=\.(?!\S))|(?<=(?<!\S)\.)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/eP8rO7/1) It can be extended to also add space in `a.b` (if between two letters). As mentioned I think you should update question with exact requirements, what this will be used for as Wiktor asked for already.

Comment: @bobblebubble edited question.

Comment: @N.M. Thanks for the update! Well, this is what my latest regex would do, wouldn't it? [Here's the demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/547648)

Comment: @bobblebubble why don't you answer the question so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex based on [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
\b(?=\.(?!\S))|(?<=(?<!\S)\.)\b
```

Would match the boundary (zero-width) between a word and a literal dot if not followed by a non-whitespace [`\S`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) or not preceded by a non-whitespace using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check.

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eP8rO7/1). Use in a PHP function with *value* parameter and replace with space.

```
// $v = character
function my_func($str, $v=".")
{
  $v = preg_quote($v, '/');
  return preg_replace('/\b(?='.$v.'(?!\S))|(?<=(?<!\S)'.$v.')\b/', " ", $str);
}
```

[PHP demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/547648)

Comment: @N.M. You mean with colon instead of dot? For that's the third paramter: [`echo my_func("here:", false, ':');`](https://eval.in/546849). Ad comment @WiktorStribiżew I don't know what's not working :) [`echo my_func("hello. 3.5/5", true);`](https://eval.in/546852)

Comment: @N.M. In my function the 1st parameter is the string. The 2nd parameter is for your third condition. It sets whether space should be added if the character borders on both sides to a word. *true* for leaving `3.5` or *false* for adding space `3 . 5`. The 3rd parameter is the character which defaults to dot. In my comment the order of the parameters was different.

Comment: my_func('hello 10+/10 :)', true, '+'); gives hello 10 +/10 :) but i would just want 'hello 10+/10 :)'. Basically i just want trailing + (meaning at the start or end of words[a-z]) to be separated from the word. If making $skip_mid = true all the time makes the regex easier, thats fine too..

Comment: basically a regex which will catch character $v if and only if its at the start and end of a word [a_z].

Comment: @N.M. Undeleted and updated. Hope this helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3 alternatives each captured into its own capture group, and use a `preg_replace_callback` to apply the corresponding replacement:

```
$wrd = ".";
$re = '~(?<=\S)(' . preg_quote($wrd) . ')(?=\S)|(?<=\S)(' . preg_quote($wrd) . ')|(' . preg_quote($wrd) . ')(?=\S)~'; 
$str = "hello.\n.hello\nhello.hello"; 
$result = preg_replace_callback($re, function($m) {
    if (!empty($m[1])) {
        return " " . $m[1] . " ";
    } else if (!empty($m[2])) {
        return " " . $m[2];
    } else return $m[3] . " ";
}, $str);
echo $result;
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/7TzfqR)

The regex will be

```
(?<=\S)(\.)(?=\S)|(?<=\S)(\.)|(\.)(?=\S)
       | 1|             | 2|  | 3|
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pD4qZ4/1)

The first group is your Case 3 (`hello.hello -> hello . hello`), the second group is your Case 1 (`hello. -> hello .`) and the third group singals your Case 2 (`.hello -> . hello`).

**UPDATE (handling exceptions)**

If you have exceptions, you can add more capturing groups. E.g., you want to protect the dot in float numbers. Add a `(\d\.\d)` alternative, and check inside the callback function if it is not empty. If not, just restore it with `return $m[n]`:

```
$wrd = ".";
$re = '~(\d\.\d)|(?<=\S)(' . preg_quote($wrd) . ')(?=\S)|(?<=\S)(' . preg_quote($wrd) . ')|(' . preg_quote($wrd) . ')(?=\S)~'; 
$str = "hello.\n.hello\nhello.hello\nhello. 3.5/5\nhello.3\na./b"; 
$result = preg_replace_callback($re, function($m) {
    if ( !empty($m[1])) {         // The dot as a decimal separator
        return $m[1];             // No space is inserted
    }
    else if (!empty($m[2])) {     // A special char is enclosed with non-spaces
        return " " . $m[2] . " "; // Add spaces around
    } else if (!empty($m[3])) {   // A special char is enclosed with non-spaces
        return " " . $m[3];       // Add a space before the special char
    } else return $m[4] . " ";    // A special char is followed with a non-space, add a space on the right
}, $str);
echo $result;
```

See an [updated code demo](http://ideone.com/OMzCP5)

Another [code demo](http://ideone.com/ixpR0B) - based on matching locations before and after the `.` that are not enclosed with spaces (and protecting a float value) (based on [@bobblebubble's solution (deleted)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36371663/3832970)):

```
$wrd = ".";
$re = '~(\d\.\d)|(?<!\s)(?=' . preg_quote($wrd) . ')|(?<=' . preg_quote($wrd) . ')(?!\s)~'; 
$str = "hello.\n.hello\nhello.hello\nhello. 3.5/5\nhello.3\na./b"; 
$result = preg_replace_callback($re, function($m) {
    if ( !empty($m[1])) {         // The dot as a decimal separator
        return $m[1];             // No space is inserted
    }
    else return " ";   // Just insert a space
}, $str);
echo $result;
```

**SUMMARY**:

- You cannot use `\b` since your `.` / `?` etc. can appear in mixed "word" and "non-word" contexts
- You need to use capturing and `preg_replace_callback` since there are different replacement schemes

Comment: I tried to run this for "hello. 3.5/5" with regex '~(?<=\S)(' . preg_quote($wrd) . ')|(' . preg_quote($wrd) . ')(?=\S)~' . I was expecting "hello . 3.5/5" however i got "hello .  3 . 5/5".

Comment: Then, you can try [`(?<=[^\s\d])(\.)(?=[^\s\d])|(?<=[^\s\d])(\.)|(\.)(?=[^\s\d])`](https://regex101.com/r/pD4qZ4/2), see [this demo](http://ideone.com/PPIlGt).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the `.` can be any non-word character. If that's the case, try this:

```
$patron = '/(\W+)/';
$this->str = trim(preg_replace($patron, ' $1 ', $this->str));
```

Answer (score 0):

`(\s?[.]\s?)`

If you use the above regex, you can simply replace all the matches with `" . "`

How it works:

I used `\s?` to capture a leading and trailing whitespace, if there is any.

`[.]` is a char class, so you should add all of the "certain characters" you want to find.

---

A regex that catches the first 2 conditions and never the third is `(\s[.]\s?|\s?[.]\s)`. (Again, you'll need to replace the capture with  `" . "`, and also add your "certain characters" to the char classes.)

You can then choose which regex you will use.